# Merge Excel sheets from a folder into a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 Excel files in a folder. I want to merge a sheet in all the files into a single sheet.

***Columns are not in same sequence so first it should look for the column header and than copy paste the data in that column.***

In every file there are multiple sheets. I need to merge only the "PIPES" worksheet.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim FileFold As String
    Dim FileSpec As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ShtCnt As Long
    Dim RowCnt As Long
    Dim Merged As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    FileFold = "C:\Users\KK\Desktop\VR"
    
    FileSpec = FileFold & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xlsx*"
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    
    'Exit if no files found
    If FileName = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="No files were found that match " & FileSpec, Buttons:=vbCritical, Title:="Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    ShtCnt = 0
    RowCnt = 1
    
    Set Merged = Workbooks.Add
    
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        ShtCnt = ShtCnt + 1
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileFold & Application.PathSeparator & FileName, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PIPES")
        With ws
        LastColumn = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            If ws.Range(1, i).Value = Merged.Worksheets(1).Range(1, j) Then
            .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Merged.Worksheets(1).Cells(RowCnt, 1)
            End If
           
        End With
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        RowCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Merged.Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A")) + 1
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox Prompt:="Finished merging.", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a job for Power Query ! You might want to look into that

Comment: There are several questions wrapped into one: 1. "How do I loop through each workbook in a folder?" 2. "How can I find a specific worksheet in a workbook?" 3. "How can I merge tables with scrambled column headers?". I suggest you look for answers to each of those three questions, and if they don't exist, ask for the answer to just 1 question at a time.

Comment: To get you started: Looping through files in a folder can be done with `Dir` or with [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object). With `Dir` you would loop until `Dir` returns blank. With FSO, you can loop `For Each File In Folder`

Comment: To get you started: Finding a worksheet in a workbook is as easy as `MyWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of Sheet")`. Or `Application.Workbooks("Name of Book").Worksheets("Name of Sheet")`. If the sheet doesn't exist, you'll get an error. to avoid the error, I like to loop through the `Worksheets` collection and search for matches, rather than directly ask for the sheet. `For Each Worksheet in MyWorkbook.Worksheets: If Worksheet.Name = "Name of Sheet" Then ... `

Comment: To get you started: unscrambling the table headers can be done with a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object). You would go through the destination table headers, adding them to the dictionary with the header name as the key and their column # as the item. This way, when you're looking at the scrambled tables, you can check to see if the header exists in the dictionary (if there is a matching header in the main table) and if yes, the dictionary tells you the column # of where to put this data.

Comment: Its looking for the worksheets, and copy pasting the data as given in source sheet. only issue is i want to copy paste the data according to coulmn headers. because columns are not in same sequence.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: tested and working for me (made a couple of fixes)-

```vb
Sub Test()
    Const FILE_ROOT As String = "C:\Users\KK\Desktop\VR\" 'use const for fixed values
    
    Dim allFiles As Collection, xlFile
    Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, ShtCnt As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsMerged As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Dim dict As Object, NextColNum As Long, colNum As Long, hdr
    
    Set allFiles = FileMatches(FILE_ROOT, "*.xlsx") 'get all Excel files
    If allFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub             'exit if no files to process
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'vbTextcompare; case-insensitive matching
    
    GoFast
    NextColNum = 0
    NextRow = 2
    Set wsMerged = Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)
    
    For Each xlFile In allFiles
        ShtCnt = ShtCnt + 1
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xlFile, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PIPES")
        With ws
            If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            LastRow = RangeLastRow(.Cells)   'last occupied row on the source sheet
            If LastRow > 1 Then              'any data to copy?
                'loop all headers in source worksheet
                For Each c In .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
                    hdr = Trim(c.Value)
                    If Len(hdr) > 0 Then
                        If Not dict.Exists(c.Value) Then 'does this header already exist on "merged" sheet?
                            NextColNum = NextColNum + 1            'next header position
                            dict.Add hdr, NextColNum               'add to dictionary
                            wsMerged.Cells(1, NextColNum).Value = hdr  'add the new header
                            Debug.Print "Added header", hdr, NextColNum, wb.Name
                        End If
                        c.Offset(1).Resize(LastRow - 1).Copy wsMerged.Cells(NextRow, dict(hdr))
                    End If 'have a header
                Next c
                NextRow = NextRow + (LastRow - 1)  'next paste row
            End If                                 'have any data to copy
        End With
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next xlFile
    
    GoFast False 'remove speed optimizations
    MsgBox Prompt:="Finished merging.", Buttons:=vbInformation, Title:="Success"
End Sub

'maximize code speed by turning off unneeded stuff
'******** must reset Calculation !
Sub GoFast(Optional SpeedUp As Boolean = True)
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = Not SpeedUp
      .Calculation = IIf(SpeedUp, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  End With
End Sub

'find the last used row in a range
Function RangeLastRow(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = rng.Find(what:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then RangeLastRow = f.row 'otherwise 0
End Function

'Get all matching files from supplied folder `root`
'  Pass False to `WarnNoMatches` to suppress message if no files found (default is True)
Function FileMatches(root As String, pattern As String, _
                     Optional WarnNoMatches As Boolean = True) As Collection
    Dim f, spec
    Set FileMatches = New Collection
    If Right(root, 1) <> "\" Then root = root & "\"
    spec = root & pattern
    f = Dir(spec)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        FileMatches.Add root & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    If FileMatches.Count = 0 And WarnNoMatches Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="No files were found that match " & spec, _
               Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="No files found"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: wsMerged.Cells(1, colNum).Value = hdr ,        c.Offset(1).Resize(LastRow - 1).Copy wsMerged.Cells(NextRow, dict(hdr))   . Its is showing error for these 2 lines.  Issue is with "colNum" and NextRow.    I tried NextRow = LastRow+1 and "NextColNum" insted of "colNum" here. But after that when it runs it is populating header only in a new excel file. I already have a template with column headers in which i want to merge all these files. In template it should look for column header and than paste the data there.

Comment: " I already have a template with column headers in which i want to merge all these files" it would have been useful to mention that - in your posted code you just add a new workbook and populate the empty sheet.